# Error when using r.watershed in QGIS 2.10.1 with Grass

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-processing, watershed

I am running [**`r.watershed`**](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass71/manuals/r.watershed.html) within QGIS processing the I get the error below.

I draw your attention to:

> GRASS_INFO_WARNING(2205,1): Subprocess failed with exit code 256 GRASS_INFO_END(2205,1)

**Does anyone know the cause of this error?**

- QGIS Pisa 2.10.1
- Tried differing machines.
- Different input DEMs.
- Outputs in memory and in folders.
- Turning off the view layers.
- Checking folder permissions.

It used to work in earlier versions on these data.

Here is the [DEM](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_5XlZJJ2R5tZVFWQlc0eXctSXM/view?usp=sharing).

Basically, it creates the output folders, finds the raster but never actually runs. Can someone maybe try the DEM on older version of QGIS. All the options can be left as default. The failure is pretty close to instant.

> GRASS_INFO_ERROR(2206,1):  USAGE for slope length determination:
>
> GRASS_INFO_ERROR(2206,1):
>   Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/grass/etc/r.watershed.ram [-4]
>   el=elevation_map t=swale_threshold [dr=drain_direction_map]
>   [de=depression_map] [ac=accumulation_map] [di=display_map]
>   [ms=max_slope_length] [ob=overland_blocking_map]
>   [S=slope_steepness_map] LS=length_slope_map [r=rill_erosion_map]
>   [sd=slope_deposition value or map]  GRASS_INFO_END(2206,1)
>
> GRASS_INFO_WARNING(2205,1): **Subprocess failed with exit code 256 
>   GRASS_INFO_END(2205,1)**

Comment: Have you tried running r.watershed via **GRASS Tools**? I found that some functions don't work successfully via the Processing Toolbox but do work in their own dedicated programs.

Comment: No, i didn´t yet, but a couple of weeks ago i used this r.watershed and worked. But now i need to do it again and using the same files and does an error

Comment: Please say which version you are using...

Comment: same for me, used to work. Using PISA

Comment: note the number of "favorite questions" this question has, i suspect others are having the same issue. Count = 2 as of now and I found some questions on the web relating to this. r.watershed is a fundamental process that the outputs from provide inputs to other tools.

Comment: @VitorPinaSilva which **`grass`** version have you installed?

Comment: @VitorPinaSilva 6.4 which comes with QGIS in OSGEO4w and Ubuntugis.

Comment: Anyone, bounty expires in 24 hours. I just tried on ubuntu 14 stable, Qgis 2,8 stable, using grass geoprocessing (tried in 7 this time) but have tired 6. Used to work.

Comment: Is this question still relevant in QGIS 2.18?